# How do I affirm that a triangle defines a plane?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

I am trying to postulate the Euclidean plane surface. I have postulates of the straight line and of extending a straight line. I want to fill the gap between a triangle and a plane. How does a triangle define a plane? Is it postulated or axiomatic or other?

Comment: A triangle is not contained in a line. What is your definition of a plane? This should help answer your question

Comment: I can affirm a triangle because I know that straight lines are straight because o 1st & 2nd Euclidean postulates. Straight lines make the sides of a triangle. There is also a definition of line-points side by side. But alas, while there is a similar definition of the plane surface (lines side by side) there is no postulate of the plane. So how do we demonstrate the truism that a triangle defines a plane...by postulate, axiom, proposition, theorem, or other?

Comment: There is the problem of knowing that lines intersect, but that's for another day.

Comment: You should know that Euclid's axioms are incomplete. In Hilbert's axioms for geometry one of the axioms states that three noncollinear points determine a unique plane.

Comment: So it is an axiom. I know that it I supposed that Euclid's axioms are incomplete and I have encountered Hilbert and found that he does a good job. But Proclus made a sharp distinction between axiom and postulate. He referred to postulates also as "petitions".. I am looking for the postulate of the plane.

Answer (score 0):

This https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hilbert's_axioms&oldid=942127286#I._Incidence link should "answer" your question. (I am intentionally using a history link: wikipedia may change and make me look like an idiot ... .)

But it does only sate properties of a plane. I would extend that to *define* a plane as the set of points on all the lines that intersect the triangle given by  the points A,B,C (that are not all on the same line) in at least 2 pints.